# Which does macOS choose when it comes to wifi vs ethernet?

Tags: macos, network

If I have both wifi on and am also connected via ethernet to my modem. Which is my system using?  I am curious because I want the ability to SSH into other devices on my local network, but I also want the 1 GB connection I have with my hard line.  So I am curious when I have multiple internet connections established, what does macOS choose to use?

Comment: Usually the first one listed. Are there devices you want to connect to which can only be reached via the WiFi of your Mac?

Comment: @nohillside yes

Comment: So these devices don’t have access to the Internet?

Comment: I can't speak for Apple devices, but typically, if these are just two connections onto the same network then a system will prefer Ethernet because it's assumed to be faster, and if they are two different networks, it will of course use the correct one depending on which network you are trying to access (which is determined based on IP addresses)

Comment: there is no public facing internet access to the devices, I can only ssh to them via wifi or physical ethernet connections.

Comment: And where does the WiFi come from? Do you use a separate hotspot (which also is not connected to the Internet) or is the Mac acting as one? Please share more details about your network setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can set its preference in the Network control panel; gear icon underneath the Services list [or ellipsis on Ventura], then drag to your preferred order.

[image]

[image]

I'm not *absolutely* sure how it decides when it then has to use WiFi instead of Ethernet, but I have always had mine set to prefer Ethernet, with WiFi also on, & it seems to have no issues with Handoff or AirDrop etc to & from my phone.

Comment: ok.  i guess what you're telling me is I can't really do what I want...  What I want is, ssh over wifi, tcp over ethernet.

Comment: How are the other devices connected? Are they on the same subnet? [If they are, then why is the route important? I feel there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: are devices that are only connected via wifi accessible via ssh on a device that is only connected via ethernet?

Comment: You're not answering my questions, only asking new ones.